# More than one application per project repository with Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-flex

I have three old applications (running on Symfony 2) where each one has been developed in separated git repositories and configured in their respective vhosts:

1. `company.com` Company website.
2. `admin.company.com` Website administration.
3. `api.company.com` API company service.

Even though, they share the same database. So we're decided (the Company) unify all of them in one application with Symfony 4 structure & approach, mainly to remove a big quantity of duplicated data and to improve its maintenance.

Right now, I'm integrating all in one application/repository as was planned, but I'm starting to deal with some performance & structure issues:

- As I've just one entry point `index.php` I did two routes prefixes to be able to access for `company.com/admin/` and `company.com/api/` sub app, so all routes are loaded each time :(
- All bundles and configuration is loaded and processed needlessly for each request. For example: when I access the API path the `SonataAdminBundle` is loaded too :(
- The cache clear command takes a long time to complete.
- The tests are breaking down and now takes a long time to complete too.

I'd like to keep the early vhost and load just the needed bundles and configuration per domains:

1. `company.com` Loads bundles, routes and configuration for a company website only (`SwiftmailerBundle`, ...)
2. `admin.company.com` Loads bundles, routes and configuration only for website administration (`SecurityBundle`, `SonataAdminBundle`, ...)
3. `api.company.com` Loads just the bundles, routes and configuration to provide a fast API company service (`SecurityBundle`, `FOSRestBundle`, `NelmioApiDocBundle`, ...)

This is what I'm doing so far:

```
// public/index.php

// ...

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$kernel = new Kernel(getenv('APP_ENV'), getenv('APP_DEBUG'));

// new method implemented in my src/kernel.php
$kernel->setHost($request->server->get('HTTP_HOST'));

$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

I've check the current host prefix in `Kernel::registerBundles()` method and I loaded the needed bundles only, but still I've problems with `bin/console` file (it doesn't work as `HTTP_HOST` variable is not defined for CLI) I'd like to clear the cache for each "sub-app" and so on.

I have been doing some research on this topic but so far I couldn't find anything helpful for my scenario (Symfony 4).

**Is possible to have many applications under one project repository running independently (like individual apps) but sharing some configuration? What is the best approach to achieve it?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Likely the [multiple kernels](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/multiple_kernels.html) approach could be a good option to solve this kind of project, but thinking now in Symfony 4 approach with environment variables, structure and kernel implementation, it could be improved.

**Name-based Virtual Kernel**

The term "Virtual Kernel" refers to the practice of running more than one application (such as `api.example.com` and `admin.example.com`) on a single project repository. Virtual kernels are "name-based", meaning that you have multiple kernel names running on each application. The fact that they are running on the same physical project repository is not apparent to the end user.

In short, each kernel name corresponds to one application.

**Application-based Configuration**

First, you'll need replicate the structure of one application for `config`, `src`, `var` directories and leave the root structure for shared bundles and configuration. It should look like this:

```
├── config/
│   ├── admin/
│   │   ├── packages/
│   │   ├── bundles.php
│   │   ├── routes.yaml
│   │   ├── security.yaml
│   │   └── services.yaml
│   ├── api/
│   ├── site/
│   ├── packages/
│   ├── bundles.php
├── src/
│   ├── Admin/
│   ├── Api/
│   ├── Site/
│   └── VirtualKernel.php
├── var/
│   ├── cache/
│   │   ├── admin/
│   │   │   └── dev/
│   │   │   └── prod/
│   │   ├── api/
│   │   └── site/
│   └── log/
```

Next, making use of the [`Kernel::$name`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/9a6d3e5557537ef606f4398f3cbe458fa775a6d9/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php#L58) property you can stand out the application to run with dedicated project files (`var/cache/<name>/<env>/*`):

- `<name><Env>DebugProjectContainer*`
- `<name><Env>DebugProjectContainerUrlGenerator*`
- `<name><Env>DebugProjectContainerUrlMatcher*`

This will be the key of the performance as each application has by definition its own DI container, routes and configuration files. Here is a complete sample of the `VirtualKernel` class that supports the previous structure:

<kbd>src/VirtualKernel.php</kbd>

```
// WITHOUT NAMESPACE!

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;

class VirtualKernel extends Kernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    private const CONFIG_EXTS = '.{php,xml,yaml,yml}';

    public function __construct($environment, $debug, $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
    }

    public function getCacheDir(): string
    {
        return $this->getProjectDir().'/var/cache/'.$this->name.'/'.$this->environment;
    }

    public function getLogDir(): string
    {
        return $this->getProjectDir().'/var/log/'.$this->name;
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array($this->environment, $this->debug, $this->name));
    }

    public function unserialize($data)
    {
        [$environment, $debug, $name] = unserialize($data, array('allowed_classes' => false));

        $this->__construct($environment, $debug, $name);
    }

    public function registerBundles(): iterable
    {
        $commonBundles = require $this->getProjectDir().'/config/bundles.php';
        $kernelBundles = require $this->getProjectDir().'/config/'.$this->name.'/bundles.php';

        foreach (array_merge($commonBundles, $kernelBundles) as $class => $envs) {
            if (isset($envs['all']) || isset($envs[$this->environment])) {
                yield new $class();
            }
        }
    }

    protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $container, LoaderInterface $loader): void
    {
        $container->setParameter('container.dumper.inline_class_loader', true);

        $this->doConfigureContainer($container, $loader);
        $this->doConfigureContainer($container, $loader, $this->name);
    }

    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollectionBuilder $routes): void
    {
        $this->doConfigureRoutes($routes);
        $this->doConfigureRoutes($routes, $this->name);
    }

    private function doConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder $container, LoaderInterface $loader, string $name = null): void
    {
        $confDir = $this->getProjectDir().'/config/'.$name;
        if (is_dir($confDir.'/packages/')) {
            $loader->load($confDir.'/packages/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        }
        if (is_dir($confDir.'/packages/'.$this->environment)) {
            $loader->load($confDir.'/packages/'.$this->environment.'/**/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        }
        $loader->load($confDir.'/services'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        if (is_dir($confDir.'/'.$this->environment)) {
            $loader->load($confDir.'/'.$this->environment.'/**/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        }
    }

    private function doConfigureRoutes(RouteCollectionBuilder $routes, string $name = null): void
    {
        $confDir = $this->getProjectDir().'/config/'.$name;
        if (is_dir($confDir.'/routes/')) {
            $routes->import($confDir.'/routes/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
        }
        if (is_dir($confDir.'/routes/'.$this->environment)) {
            $routes->import($confDir.'/routes/'.$this->environment.'/**/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
        }
        $routes->import($confDir.'/routes'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
    }
}
```

Now your `\VirtualKernel` class requires an extra argument (`name`) that defines the application to load. In order for the autoloader to find your new `\VirtualKernel` class, make sure add it to `composer.json` autoload section:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "src/VirtualKernel.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Admin\\": "src/Admin/",
        "Api\\": "src/Api/",
        "Site\\": "src/Site/"
    }
},
```

Then, run `composer dump-autoload` to dump the new autoload config.

**Keeping one entry point for all applications**

```
├── public/
│   └── index.php
```

Following the same filosofy of Symfony 4, whereas environment variables decides which development environment and debug mode should be used to run your application, you could add a new `APP_NAME` environment variable to set the application to execute:

<kbd>public/index.php</kbd>

```
// ...

$kernel = new \VirtualKernel(getenv('APP_ENV'), getenv('APP_DEBUG'), getenv('APP_NAME'));
// ...
```

For now, you can play with it by using PHP's built-in Web server, prefixing the new application environment variable:

```
$ APP_NAME=site php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public
$ APP_NAME=admin php -S 127.0.0.1:8001 -t public
$ APP_NAME=api php -S 127.0.0.1:8002 -t public
```

**Executing commands per application**

```
├── bin/
│   └── console.php
```

Add a new console option `--kernel` to be able to run commands from different applications:

<kbd>bin/console</kbd>

```
// ...
$name = $input->getParameterOption(['--kernel', '-k'], getenv('APP_NAME') ?: 'site');

//...
$kernel = new \VirtualKernel($env, $debug, $name);
$application = new Application($kernel);
$application
    ->getDefinition()
    ->addOption(new InputOption('--kernel', '-k', InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The kernel name', $kernel->getName()))
;
$application->run($input);
```

Later, use this option to run any command different to default one (`site`).

```
$ bin/console about -k=api
```

Or if you prefer, use environment variables:

```
$ export APP_NAME=api
$ bin/console about                         # api application
$ bin/console debug:router                  # api application
$
$ APP_NAME=admin bin/console debug:router   # admin application
```

Also you can configure the default `APP_NAME` environment variable in the `.env` file.

**Running tests per application**

```
├── tests/
│   ├── Admin/
│   │   └── AdminWebTestCase.php
│   ├── Api/
│   ├── Site/
```

The `tests` directory is pretty similar to the `src` directory, just update the `composer.json` to map each directory `tests/<Name>/` with its PSR-4 namespace:

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Admin\\Tests\\": "tests/Admin/",
        "Api\\Tests\\": "tests/Api/",
        "Site\\Tests\\": "tests/Site/"
    }
},
```

Again, run `composer dump-autoload` to re-generate the autoload config.

Here, you might need create a `<Name>WebTestCase` class per application in order to execute all tests together:

<kbd>test/Admin/AdminWebTestCase</kbd>

```
namespace Admin\Tests;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

abstract class AdminWebTestCase extends WebTestCase
{
    protected static function createKernel(array $options = array())
    {
        return new \VirtualKernel(
            isset($options['environment']) ? $options['environment'] : 'test',
            isset($options['debug']) ? $options['debug'] : true,
            'admin'
        );
    }
}
```

Later, extends from `AdminWebTestCase` to test `admin.company.com` application (Do the same for another ones).

**Production and vhosts**

Set the environment variable `APP_NAME` for each vhost config in your production server and development machine:

```
<VirtualHost company.com:80>       
    SetEnv APP_NAME site

    # ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost admin.company.com:80>        
    SetEnv APP_NAME admin

    # ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost api.company.com:80>
    SetEnv APP_NAME api

    # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

**Adding more applications to the project**

With three simple steps you should be able to add new vKernel/applications to the current project:

1. Add to `config`, `src` and `tests` directories a new folder with the `<name>` of the application and its content.
2. Add to `config/<name>/` dir at least the `bundles.php` file.
3. Add to `composer.json` autoload/autoload-dev sections the new PSR-4 namespaces for `src/<Name>/` and `tests/<Name>` directories and update the autoload config file.

Check the new application running `bin/console about -k=<name>`.

Final directory structure:

```
├── bin/
│   └── console.php
├── config/
│   ├── admin/
│   │   ├── packages/
│   │   ├── bundles.php
│   │   ├── routes.yaml
│   │   ├── security.yaml
│   │   └── services.yaml
│   ├── api/
│   ├── site/
│   ├── packages/
│   ├── bundles.php
├── public/
│   └── index.php
├── src/
│   ├── Admin/
│   ├── Api/
│   ├── Site/
│   └── VirtualKernel.php
├── tests/
│   ├── Admin/
│   │   └── AdminWebTestCase.php
│   ├── Api/
│   ├── Site/
├── var/
│   ├── cache/
│   │   ├── admin/
│   │   │   └── dev/
│   │   │   └── prod/
│   │   ├── api/
│   │   └── site/
│   └── log/
├── .env
├── composer.json
```

Unlike *multiple kernel files* approach, this version reduces a lot of code duplication and files; just one kernel, `index.php` and `console` for all applications, thanks to environment variables and virtual kernel class.

Example based-on Symfony 4 skeleton: https://github.com/yceruto/symfony-skeleton-vkernel
Inspired in https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/multiple_kernels.html

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write such a detailed answer, really helped me out!

Answer (score 1):

You can create new environments like: `admin`, `website`, `api`. Then by provide environment variable `SYMFONY_ENV` by apache/nginx you will be able to run dedicated application and still use sub domains `company.com`, `admin.company.com`, `api.company.com`. Also you will be able to easily load only required routing.

Depends from how many application you want to create based on this approach you can add conditions to load specified bundles by project in `AppKernel` class or create separate classes for each project.

You should also read this article https://jolicode.com/blog/multiple-applications-with-symfony2

Answer (score 0):

Also when you want to run Behat testing, you should run it with this command:

for windows:

```
set APP_NAME=web&& vendor\bin\behat
```

for linux:

```
export APP_NAME='web' && vendor\bin\behat
```

where "web" is your kernel name you want to run.

Answer (score 0):

The KernelInterface::getName() method and the kernel.name parameter have been deprecated. There's no alternative to them because this is a concept that no longer makes sense in Symfony applications.

If you need a distinctive ID for the kernel of the application, you can use the KernelInterface::getContainerClass() method and the kernel.container_class parameter.

Similarly, the getRootDir() method and the kernel.root_dir parameter have been deprecated too. The alternative is to use the getProjectdir() and kernel.project_dir method introduced in Symfony 3.3

See https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-2-important-deprecations#deprecated-the-kernel-name-and-the-root-dir